# Open MS Access from the Command line

Tags: windows, command-line

Why is it that if I type `calc` then enter in the command line the calculator opens, but when I type MSAccess in the command line it says

```
    'msaccess' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or bath file
```

I know there is a way to fix this and set it up, I have searched the web, but I don't know what to look for. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means that there is no executable program named `msaccess` available anywhere on your path. "The path" refers to a list of paths search by the command line when searching for an executable. This list is stored in the `%PATH%` environment variable, and is separated by semi-colons.

There are only a few possibilities:

- You are misspelling the program name, or it does not really exist. Navigate to the Access executable under `C:\Program Files` and verify that it is really spelled `msaccess` (and that it is installed). Incidentally, I just verified this on my system, so `msaccess` would appear to be the correct command.
- The folder which contains `msaccess` is not in the `%PATH%` variable. Type `echo %PATH%` to find out. If not, you can [add it to the path.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28778358/712526)
- The only other possibility (very unlikely, but mentioned here for completeness sake) is that the file exists in the path, but is not actually an executable.

Comment: Very good answer!

Comment: I forgot one other possibility: your universe doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to  jpaugh, it is also possible to open a command-prompt in the folder where the `msaccess` executable is located (i.e if the folder is missing in the `%PATH%` variable).

To do this right click and press shift simultaneously anywhere  in the target folder e.g in my case I have Microsoft office 2016, so in the case the location of my executable is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microft Office\Office16`

So if I right click and press shift I can open a command prompt, which when I enter `msaccess` I can start Microsoft Access without that error